# forever graceful exit can not emit any process signal event

Tags: node.js, forever

I use forever to keep my nodejs program running all the time.

When I use command to terminate node process, before program exit, I want to do something, command as below:

```
forever stop + <id>  //get id by forever list
```

But no process signal is emitted.(SIGINT,SIGTERM,SIGKILL ...), is this forever's bug?

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Edit:
start program by :

```
forever index.js // not forever start index.js
```

[start program image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtCBH.png)

stop by another command prompt:

[stop program image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u7XP.png)

Answer (score 0):

As [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) says, Using processId as forever parameter is deprecated, I think you just have to execute this command with your main server file like this :

```
// Start your server
forever start /path/to/your/server/file.js

// Stop your server
forever stop /path/to/your/server/file.js
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I use id (get by forever list) to stop the process. 'forever start' can not really start the program, I will add more description, sorry for confused.